# VBA-Query Loop - Unable to convert to Form reference

Tags: ms-access, vba

All,

I've tried searching through the site and now, I am unable to find an answer to this question. If someone could point me to the right direction- I'd appreciate it.

I have a form with 10 combo-boxes. Once user selects a value in CB1- CB2 becomes visible and active.

I am trying to run a dynamic query- where the selection of the combo-box is used to select a column from my table called "dbo_animals"

To elaborate:
CB1 contains the following values -

> elephant, giraffe, bufffalo, tiger, lion

Once the user selects elephant in CB1, CB2 becomes active and I select tiger next. So the query becomes like. The process can go on and the user can select up to 10 animals

```
**SELECT elephant, tiger FROM dbo_animals**
```

Problem:

I am able to create the query with string manipulation- Unfortunately due to the way the loop through controls is set up- The query is unable to convert the text into a reference

If I hard code it as `tempquery = "SELECT [Form]![Animal Finder]![CB1] FROM dbo_animals"
MsgBox(tempquery)` it looks like

```
SELECT Elephant from dbo_animals
```

This is how I want. But, since i am looping through CB controls, I have it set up as

```
tempquery = "SELECT" & " [Form]![Animal Finder]![CB" & i & "] FROM dbo_animals"
```

and this shows up as

```
SELECT [Form]![Animal Finder]![CB1] FROM dbo_animals
```

thereby giving me an error saying that the reference is not valid. Which makes sense, since it is unable to evaluate the text as a reference.

How can I fix this? Or how do I correct the text into a reference?

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the Selected items of your ListBox, and build a comma separated list that you will then be able to use with a SQL `IN` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo_Animals WHERE filed1 IN ("elephant", "giraffe", "lion")
```

To build such a string, you can find some help [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/827423).